# How to decode string to russian character

Tags: ios, swift

I have 1_1_1%D0%B0 string and i need to decode  1_1_1а ?

```
extension String {
    var decodingNumericEntities: String {
        let nsMutableString = NSMutableString(string: self)
        CFStringTransform(nsMutableString, nil, "Any-Hex/XML10" as CFString, true)
        return nsMutableString as String
    }
}
```

I try this but not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your characters are percent-encoded, so you can try

```
var decoded = self.removingPercentEncoding ?? self
```